# Parse the Date input value to State React

Tags: arrays, reactjs, datatable, daterangepicker

i have a component that filters the array based on range of dates(from,to) i have created the filter with hardcoded values and i want to get input from user and filter from array i uploaded my code below

React Code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";
import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";

import { registerLocale } from "react-datepicker";
import ro from 'date-fns/locale/ro';
registerLocale('ro', ro)

class MyDatepickerComponent extends Component {

  state = {
    startDate: new Date(),
    endDate: new Date(),
    datefilter:[]
  };

  handleChange = (date, event) => {
    console.log('onChange', date, event);
    this.setState({
      startDate: date
    });
  };
  handleChanges = (date, event) => {
    console.log('onChange', date, event);
    this.setState({
      endDate: date
    });
  };
  async componentDidMount() {
    var startDate = new Date("2021-12-10T17:31:00.000Z").getTime();
    var endDate = new Date().getTime();
    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8081/items');
    const data = await response.json();
    var result = data.filter(d => {
      var time = new Date(d.Date).getTime();
      return (startDate < time && time < endDate);
    });
    console.log(result);
    this.setState({ datefilter: result })
  }

  async onFormSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var startDate = new Date(this.state.startDate).getTime();
    var endDate = new Date("2021-12-14T18:31:00.000Z").getTime();
    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8081/items');
    const data = await response.json();
    var result = data.filter(d => {
      var time = new Date(d.Date).getTime();
      return (startDate < time && time < endDate);
    });
    console.log(result);
    this.setState({ datefilter: result })
  }

  render() {
const datefilter = this.state.datefilter
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.onFormSubmit}>
        <DatePicker
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          selected={this.state.startDate}
          showTimeSelect
          dateFormat="MM/dd/yyyy  EE hh:mm a"
          locale="en"
        />
        <DatePicker
          onChange={this.handleChanges}
          selected={this.state.endDate}
          showTimeSelect
          dateFormat="MM/dd/yyyy  EE hh:mm a"
          locale="en"
        />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
        
        <table style={{}} class="table">
          <thead class="thead-dark">
            <tr>
              <th scope="col">Item ID</th>
              <th scope="col">Item Name</th>
              <th scope="col">Status</th>
              <th scope="col">Date</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {datefilter.map(table => (
              <tr>
                <td>{table.ID}</td>
                <td>{table.ItemName}</td>
                <td>{table.Status}</td>
                <td>{table.Date}</td>
              </tr>
            ))}
          </tbody>
        </table>

      </div>
    )
  };
}
```

export default MyDatepickerComponent;
i want to change the startdate and enddate based on user input kindly helpme to do this

Comment: looks like you're importing `DateRangePicker` from a library, read its docs and see what props need to be passed to make it a controlled component

Comment: @RameshReddy Even if its normal input means ok( like input type="Date") i want to pass the start date and enddate using user input kindly guide me